# CUDA - thread usage - copy one image after another into a buffer

Tags: image, cuda, copy, buffer

I have a set of images that come from a camera and I need to store these images in CUDA device memory and render it using OpenGL. These images have to be stored one after another, contiguously, in a buffer.

The questions I have are:

1. Let there be 10 images that I need to store in a buffer, how do I do the correct thread assignment?
2. I want to know if the program I wrote is correct?

I have pasted only the kernel code; I allocated memory for `Buffer` and `EnergyImg` in the host code separately:

```
const unsigned int tidx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
const unsigned int tidy = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

const unsigned int adx =  tidx + tidy * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

const unsigned int bdx = adx; 

int TotalFrames = 10;

for(int a = 1; a<=TotalFrames; a++)
{

    int SingleFrame = (m_ImageHeight * m_ImageWidth);

    int CurrentFrame = a * (m_ImageHeight * m_ImageWidth);  
    // (first/next) frame is stored till the end of this value

    int PreviousFrame = (a-1) * (m_ImageHeight * m_ImageWidth); 
    // next frame will be stored in memory from the end of previous frame

    if (  (a==1) )
    {               
        if (adx < CurrentFrame)
        {
            Buffer[adx] = EnergyImg[adx];                                                        
        }
    }

    else if((a > 1) && (a <= TotalFrames))
    {
        if( ((adx > PreviousFrame) && (adx <= CurrentFrame)) )
        {
            while ( bdx < SingleFrame)
            { 
                Buffer[adx] = EnergyImg[bdx];                                                                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not run your code and see if it produces the correct results first?

Comment: I did. It does compiles and builds perfectly in both debug and release.
However, when I do it in real time and try to render it, I get access violation errors. Probably because there is no input being stored in the buffer and therefore, nothing to render.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks quite broken to me, but you're probably also barking up the wrong tree.

1. An access violation coming from another piece of code which you
   haven't shown is not likely to be related to this code.  This code
   does not do any allocation that I can see (and I wouldn't expect GPU
   device code to be creating buffers that OGL will use for rendering).  This code might certainly affect the data in a buffer, but should not affect the size or number of buffers that are available, or the ability to access them.
2. I think there are many possible problems with this code.  As one example, a construct like this is almost certainly broken:

   ```
       while ( bdx < SingleFrame)
       { 
           Buffer[adx] = EnergyImg[bdx];
       }
   ```

   Please consider whether or not this code is guaranteed to lead to an infinite loop.  Never mind CUDA or GPUs.  If this were straight C code, under what circumstances could the `while` loop, once entered, actually exit?  `bdx` is certainly unmodifiable, since you have declared it with `const`.  If `bdx` satisfies the while condition once, it will satisfy the while condition forever (since nothing in your while loop or anywhere in your code modifies `SingleFrame`, once it's value is established.)

Comment: 1. Obviously, you are right about this being a piece of code from a greater chunk. To allocate memory, I used cudaMalloc and copied the data that I needed for ImageHeight and ImageWidth with cudaMemcpy. The reason why I am getting access violation errors is because when I compile and build the project that this code is a part of, I get an application that should be integrated with Labview. Labview, in turn, has a couple of DLLs which are loaded into it that acquires and pre-processes OCT images. The code that I am writing is an extension of the pre-processing.

Comment: I'm not sure your comment affects anything I said.  1. This code, whether properly populating buffers or putting garbage in them, could not be the cause of an access violation elsewhere.  2. This code has an infinite loop in it (and may well be broken in other ways.)

Comment: To render the images, I do use the simple CUDA-GL interop process which is available from the 'CUDA-by example' text book. It is during rendering that I am actually getting access violation errors. 

2. I had thought about this code leading into an infinite loop. That is the reason why I needed a second opinion from you :) 
I will probably have to modify the conditional statements for the data if I need it to exit the while loop.

Comment: An additional question I had was: Once the thread finishes its work by copying the data from the current index, how do I get the threads to go back to index 0? 

Do I use __syncthreads() at the end of the copy operation?

Comment: My concern is that you don't really understand CUDA programming.  But it's not possible to determine your knowledge gaps, nor give a tutorial in SO comments.  Having said that, `adx` and `bdx` are variables.  You can assign them in any way that seems appropriate to you.  `__syncthreads()` is a [barrier](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions) for threads in a thread block, it has nothing to do with specific index variables.  You might also wish to consider taking some [basic CUDA webinars](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars).

Comment: Haha, yes, I'm not really familiar with CUDA or SO. I've started learning CUDA and I'm interested. Yeah, will do. Thank you for being patient and explaining stuff though! Helps a lot :)